# Why an infinite loop begins if I try to update my state with API response data?

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, promise

I'm a little bit unexperienced with promises and asynchronous code and I'm building my first project with API calls.

My situation is this: I have to call Spotify API first time to get an auth token and then call it again to fetch my data with this token.

This is my code:

```
const FeaturedAlbums = () => {
  const [featuredAlbums, setFeaturedAlbums] = useState([]);

  const getToken = async () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.REACT_APP_ENCODED_KEY}`,
      },
      data: params,
    });

    const accessToken = res.data.access_token;

    return accessToken;
  };

  const getFeaturedAlbums = async (token) => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      params: {
        limit: 6,
      },
    });

    const albums = res.data.albums.items;
    // console.log(albums);

    const myAlbums = albums.map((album) => ({
      artist: album.artists[0].name,
      img: album.images[1].url,
      title: album.name,
    }));
    console.log(myAlbums);
    return myAlbums;
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    const myToken = await getToken();
    console.log(myToken);

    const newAlbums = await getFeaturedAlbums(myToken);
    setFeaturedAlbums(newAlbums);
  });
```

I'm doing something very wrong with promises for sure but I need some hints.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

First, your `useEffect` has no dependencies, and I believe that's what causing the infinite loop. As stated in [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), a `useEffect` hook will run after the first render **and** after every update. Try passing an empty array `[]` as the second parameter of the hook, and your hook will be run once, after the first render.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // your code here
  }, []) // <-- empty array
```

Also, that's not how you should use async within a hook. You should define your async function **in the hook**, and call it right after, like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function myAsyncFunc() {
      // do all the async job here
    }
    myAsyncFunc();
  }, []);
```